# How can we fit a box inside a cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

We have a box (not necessarily a cube) in 3D space with known vertices. And we know the normal vector of the apex of a right cone (or we know the axis of the cone) and the cone angle ($a$ in the figure).

[image: The cone is 3D although it is shown as 2D.]

*The cone is 3D, the 2D presentation is for simplicity.*

How can we find the coordinates of the cone apex ($P$) for the smallest cone confiding the box?

Solving in 2D is very easy as we can quickly calculate the angles and sides of the triangle. However, in 3D, I could not figure out which vertices of the box are hitting the cone. In other words, I need to find the two vertices which limit the cone.

Comment: I assume you mean _cone_ in the title?

Comment: @an4s my bad :p I fixed the typo.

Comment: Is it  a "nice" cone? Is the box face perpendicular to the cone axis?

Comment: @Moti by "nice" you mean right cone? The box can be in any direction. If it was perpendicular, it would be the 2D case I mentioned.

Comment: So I assume a right cone. There are more than one solution assuming a non-cube box. There are at least 3 solution in which 6 vertices touch the cone and another 3 in which 4 vertices touch the cone. Could envision more than 6 different solutions.

Comment: @Moti $P$ is on a given line (the cone axis). There is only one solution where $P$ is closets to the box (the smallest possible cone).

Comment: What is the definition of "smallest cone"? Height? Volume? Base? I think that the solution is where 6 vertices touch the cone.

Comment: @Moti since the cone angle is prescribed, there is only one smallest cone, which has the smallest volume and smallest height. Depending on the box direction, only 4 vertices can touch the cone. In any case, you are right. We need to find a cone which touches at least 4 vertices.

Comment: I assume that you refer to a solution that has a face perpendicular to the axis. If you find such, you can slide it along the side to allow 6 vertices to touch the cone - I believe that this one will have the smallest cone.

Comment: @Moti The positions of the box and the cone apex are fixed. We just have to find the closest the cone apex can get to the box while preserving the prescribed angle.

Comment: I see - than create the vectors to the vertices and use the one that has the smallest dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every vertex $V_k$ of the cuboid find its projection $H_k$ on the axis
and construct two points $P_k$, $P'_k$ on the axis such that
$$
P_kH_k=P'_kH_k={V_kH_k\over\tan(a/2)}.
$$

Those two points among $\{P_k,P'_k\}$ containing all the other points between them are the two possible vertices of the smallest cones.